# Why is using "SYS" not recommended when manipulating an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle

When working with Oracle databases I often read that one should not use SYS to manipulate a database (create tables, constraints, sequences, synonyms etc.). Why is it not recommended? Some of my colleagues argue that as long as you use fully qualified descriptors, there should be no problem with using SYS. Is this true?
Which problems could be caused in which scenarios by manipulating a database as SYS?

Comment: Ask your colleagues if they are working as `root` on their computers. Working as `SYS` is the same as working as `root`- you only do that for maintenance work, but not to write an email or document.

Answer (score 1):

> Which problems could be caused in which scenarios by manipulating a
>   database as SYS?

Both, `SYS` and `SYSTEM` are `default` users, created with the creation of the database. Although they have much power - as they are granted the `DBA role` - they're still ordinary users. Because `SYS` owns the data dictionary, he is considered a bit more special than `SYSTEM`.

But `SYS` has the SYSDBA privilege which SYSTEM doesn't. This makes it possible for `SYS` to become a very very powerful user. 
The difference becomes clear if you try to `shutdown` the database as ordinary `SYS`: you get `insufficient privileges` as result. However, if connected as SYSDBA, it's possible.

Note, `SYSDBA` is not a role, it is a `privilege`.

SYS is also special in that **it is not possible to create a trigger** in the sys schema. Also, a logon trigger is not executed when sys connects to the database.

**SYS**

`SYS` is the owner of the database and the owner of the data dictionary.

Never ever create objects in the SYS schema.

The objects belonging to SYS cannot be exported.

**SYSTEM**

`SYSTEM` is a privileged administration user, and typically owns Oracle provided tables other than the dictionary. Don't create your own objects under SYSTEM.

Answer (score 1):

Because SYS owns the database.

It can do anything. If your colleagues forget to  prefix the target object with the target schema they could corrupt the SYS schema and/or damage the database.

I would be concerned if too many people knew the SYS password. Because it creates auditing problems. When something goes wrong, and it will,  it's harder to know who was responsible unless they own up. Not saying a blame culture is a good culture, but people are more careful when they know they are accountable.

This is not just a safety thing.  it's not only accidental corruption you need to worry about about. A bad actor with the SYS password can sabotage the database, steal code (IPR) and of course siphon confidential data.

Maybe you are just talking about Development and your organization does things properly in Production. I do hope so.

Using SYS is like taking a shortcut across the railway tracks. Probably you will be fine but why take the risk?